# React Native: Fix TextInput at the bottom of the screen with a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I need to fix the input in the bottom of the screen, so that keyboard pushes this input (similar to instagram comments).

Here's an example():
`https://snack.expo.io/LPRwoGpik`

It's working fine, but if I put the `FlatList` inside the `ScrollView` the bottom input is dissapearing.

What's the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<View style={{flex: 1,}} >
        <ScrollView>
          {content}
        </ScrollView>
        <TextInput style={{position: "absolute", bottom :0}}/>

     </View>
```

Comment: Please check the example in the question. The TextInput should be wrapped into KeyboardAvoidingView